# Understing Oauth2 flow with angular

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, discord

I think I am doing this wrong.

How can I authorize a user and send the access token to the frontend (Angular) and also make api requests to fetch the user's avatar..etc

In my application, I use discord oauth2 with passport-discord. I call my backend (nodejs) like like this:

```
login() {
    this.commonService.showLoadingOverlay();
    return this.http.get('/auth/login/').subscribe((data: any) => {
      const token = data.token;
      this.token = token;
      if (token) {
        this.userInfo = data.user;
        this.userId = data.user.user_id;
        this.discordId = data.user.discord_id;
        this.authStatusListener.next(true);
        this.isAuthenticated = true;
        const expiresInDuration = data.expiresIn;
        const now = new Date();
        const expirationDate = new Date(now.getTime() + expiresInDuration * 10000);
        this.saveAuthData(token, expirationDate, this.userId, this.userInfo);
        this.setAuthTimer(expiresInDuration);

        this.commonService.hideLoadingOverlay();
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }
    }, error => {
      this.commonService.hideLoadingOverlay();
      this.router.navigate(['/'])
      const message = 'Not logged in...'
      this.commonService.showErrorMessage(message);
    }

    )
  }
```

Backend:

```
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    if (req.user) {
        const token = jwt.sign({ userId: req.user.user_id, discordId: req.user.discord_id },
            process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
            { expiresIn: '6h' });
            
        res.status(200).json({
            token: token,
            expiresIn: 3600,
            user: req.user
        });
    } else {
        res.send('not logged in!')
    }

});
```

Discord Strategy:

```
    passport.use(new DiscordStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT,
    clientSecret: process.env.DISCORD_SECRET,
    callbackURL: process.env.DISCORD_REDIRECT,
    scope: scopes
},
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        const currentQuery = 'SELECT user_id, discord_id FROM users WHERE discord_id= $1';
        const currentUserValues = [profile.id];
        db.query(currentQuery, currentUserValues, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else if (!err && res.rows[0]) {
                const currentUser = res.rows[0];
                done(null, currentUser); //send to serilize
            } else if (!err && !res.rows[0]) {
                const newUserQuery = 'INSERT INTO users (discord_id, discord_email) VALUES ($1,$2) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING user_id'
                const newUserValues = [profile.id, profile.email]
                db.query(newUserQuery, newUserValues, (err, res) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        const newUser = res.rows[0];
                        done(null, newUser); //send to serilize
                    }
                });

            }
        })

    }));
```

I am certain that I am doing it wrong and I am unable to find the right way to do it? What's the best practice? how do I get the token and use it with other api calls?

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you sending the expiration time of 3600s separately? That information of token expiry that you are declaring 6h is itself in the token.

Instead of sending the token as a plain JSON, try adding it to the header

```
res.setHeader('your_token_name', token);
```

In order to access the headers on Angular side, you have to expose them from the node.js

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'your_token_name');
```

You can save that token in the session storage on the Angular doing something like this

```
sessionStorage.setItem('token', responseData.headers.get('your_token_name'));
```

Then, you can send the token to the node.js on each request by adding an HTTP Interceptor.

Comment: But how do I access the token so that I can set it in the headers? Do I do it inside the discord strategy? Beacause that's the only place I can get the token from (profile.accessToken) because I want to use the token with other request, and I believe storing it in the database is not secure .I fixed the expiration time, thanks.

Comment: You're creating the token when the user logs in and assigning the token to the variable `token`. This is your token. You can set that in the response header by naming it anything you want. For example, I am naming it `x-access-token` so, I would probably do `res.setHeader('x-access-token', token)`

Comment: You don't have to store the token in your database. In order to protect the API and check for the token validity on each request, just use the `JWT.verify()` functionality.

Comment: You don't have to send the token on each request. It doesn't work like that. Token gets generated when the user logs in. You send it to the Angular by attaching it to the response header. On Angular side, you store that token on session storage or local storage. `I would prefer session storage` Then, on each request from Angular to the Node, you attach that stored token in the HTTP request by doing it manually for each request or, by using `HTTP Interceptor` that will do it for you each time Angular sends a request to Node. You can then use `JWT.verify()` to check for token validity

Comment: Thanks, it's more clear now although I have to read more into out to understand it completely :)